# Can i wire ceiling fan ( no light) and 2 recessed lights on One dimmer switch?

Tags: lighting

I have 3 romex lines (black and white)coming into switch box.

- Recessed lights
- Fan
- Power from breaker

If I want 1 dimmer switch how do i connect?

Comment: Fans can't be dimmed. Using a dimmer on a fan can set it on fire.

Comment: Even if a dimmer could be used for the fan, the results wouldn’t equal your expectation.

Comment: I'm not suite **why** you would want one dimmer switch. Then you couldn't have bright light for reading + low fan speed so papers don't blow around the room or low light for watching TV + high fan speed for comfort on a hot day.

Answer (score 1):

### You'll need a special sort of dimmer for this

What you need for this job isn't an ordinary dimmer switch, it's a combination dimmer/fan speed controller.  Fortunately, this isn't too rare a product (most of the major lighting controls manufacturers make them).

Once you have one (get one that's a self-contained unit vs. one that needs a module in the fan base), simply wire it as per the instructions, and you should have speed control of the fan *and* dimmed lights at that point.  (If you get stuck, ask another question here, specifying the make and model of the fan controller in question.)